# Can you pickpocket a protectron to death?

Tags: fallout-3

If I were to pickpocket all the energy cells out of a protecton, would it run out of power and shut down?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. The energy cells are used as ammo for the Protectron's weapons only. It doesn't use them as a power source.

However, if you pickpocket their ammo, they will no longer be able to fire their weapons. This doesn't mean the amount of ammo they have defines how often they can fire, this is actually unlimited so long as they have at least one round.

[image: Protectron]

Comment: Will they not be able to shoot after taking all the ammo?

Comment: @Ronan - Updated answer.

Comment: However, with the [Robotics Expert](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Robotics_Expert) perk, you can sneak up to a Protectron (as if to pick pocket) and shut it down.

Comment: Or if you pickpocket it you can leave a pulse grenade or mine in there and it will go off, damaging or killing the protectron.

Comment: Its easier to whack that stupid thing to death. Run around in circles and keep whacking. Same old same old.